# .editorconfig file in GitHub

Tags: github, editorconfig

I'm trying to add an .editorconfig to our github repo to make the github code viewer display tabs as 4 spaces. This sounded pretty simple and GitHUb supposedly offers native support for it, however I can't get it to work.

I've added the following .editorconfig to the root of our repo:

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# 4 space indentation
[*.{cpp,h,cs,xaml,editorconfig}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

#   #   #
#   #   #
```

Those last 2 lines with hashes are done with tabs and spaces respectively. When I open this file in the github code viewer, the first line shows with tabs as 8 spaces. If I add ?ts=4 to the URL the tabs do display as 4 spaces.

Am I just using this wrong/expecting it to do something it doesn't? Our issue is older code in the repo was added with tabs, and we wanted to start using tabs as spaces (4 spaces) in new code, so we wanted the existing tabs to display aligned with the new ones.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: "GitHub supposedly offers native support for it" ← Where did you see this? I'm unaware of any such support, and a quick search was unable to find any mention of it.

Comment: They mention it late in this thread, saying GitHub recently added native support: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/170

Also if you look on http://editorconfig.org/ they have GitHub listed as one of the platforms where editorconfig is recognised by default.

Comment: [That comment](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/170#issuecomment-150489692) suggests that setting `indent_style = tab` is necessary for this to work, but your file has `indent_style = space`. See if changing that setting helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GitHub does in fact support EditorConfig, though I'm not sure they've ever officially announced this.  They wrote the [Ruby core library](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-core-ruby) for EditorConfig.

As for your issue, it may be a bug in the GitHub support.  The in-browser text editor used on GitHub is limited in a number of ways that makes EditorConfig support tricky.  I can't remember whether this specific issue was a problem though.

There is a [web browser extension that adds more complete EditorConfig support](https://github.com/RReverser/github-editorconfig#readme).  You might want to use that extension and see if it works.  If so, an issue should be submitted to GitHub with instructions for reproducing the problem.

Comment: I was aware there were specific extensions, but I was expecting this to be obsolete now. I installed it to try, and it turns out it suddenly works. Also curious to note that while it works when looking at a file, it doesn't seem to work when comparing revisions (eg. reviewing pull request, which is really our main usecase :( ) - is this known and a limitation, or worth reporting as well?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that limitation is known. Definitely worth reporting. I'd suggest referencing this question in your issue as well. :)

Comment: Tiny test repo for it: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-editorconfig